# How to properly override OpenVPN's redirect-gateway on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

My VPN provider pushes `redirect-gateway` and I don't like that.

On Windows, I override this with routes as advised [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway):

```
route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

But on Linux, I can't get incoming connections with this method. What would be Linux equivalent? Note that I do get incoming connections when gateway is redirected, so NAT/port forwarding doesn't seem to be issue here.

I run Arch Linux with stock kernel 3.15.7. My networking stack consists of NetworkManager 0.9.10.0, iproute2 3.15.0, wpa_supplicant 2.2. OpenVPN version is 2.3.4.